# Monaca and IndexedDB

Tags: angularjs, indexeddb, monaca

I have been confusing about using IndexedDB on Monaca Debugger for iOS9.

When I run the following code, Monaca debugger return "You can't use IndexedDB". I believe IndexedDB have been supported from iOS8.
Would you help me please?

```
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB;
    if (indexedDB) {
        var app = {}
        app.indexedDB = {};
        app.indexedDB.db = null;
    } else {
    window.alert("You can't use IndexedDB");
    }
```

Comment: try executing `window.indexedDB`, what's the output?